# Subtract / Divide two lists of digits

Tags: recursion, lisp

I want to represent numbers as lists of digits. How can I add subtract and divide the two numbers even if they are of different size ?
For example : 100 - 12 = 88  is equivalent to (1 0 0 ) minus ( 1 2) = ( 8 8)
              100 / 12 = 8  is equivalent to  (1 0 0 ) divided by (1 2 ) = (8)

Comment: There are already similar questions on Stack Overflow about this sort of question, i.e., arithmetic with list of digits.  In addition to showing your code, you should also take a look at those.

Comment: Mentioning "even if they are of different size" suggests that you have code that works with lists of digits that are the same length.  If that's the case, then (in addition to showing the code that works for that), it seems like a more specific question would simply be "how can I pad the lists with digits so that my existing code works"?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to represent numbers as digits in decimal. Lets imagine I want to represent the number `123`. One obvious one is to do it from most significant digit to least like `(1 2 3)`. Thats good for presentation only. The other way is to do it least to most significant  `(3 2 1)`.

When adding and substracting you add from the least significant digits and if the sum is above 9 you carry (add 1 to the next digit in one of the numbers) and continue recursing.

So do you know how to long add? If so this will be a piece of cake to do. `123 + 49` is `(+ '(9 4) '(3 2 1)) ; ==> (2 7 1)`. Good luck!